# Can I join bank as a sales professional

Tags: sharia

I belong to Muslim family , I have got a job offer in a bank as a sales professional. Where I will be dealing with clients willing to invest money in the bank.

But my family, they don't want me to go for this job as banking job is considered haram in Islam. I used to give away my interest money and also give zakat every year. Even after performing all those acts which are sunnat in Islam, can I go for this job?

Comment: As a first step, if you're REALLY keen on learning the right answer, please take a moment to slowly and correctly type in your question in ENGLISH and NOT in SMS language. If you can't do this, why do you think others should spend time answering?!

Answer (score 1):

Simple Answer is No..
Because if whoever is involved directly in interest (as Banks directly are running on interest) then it is wrong in islam to work in banks in all ways..

Scholars already agree on this issue

Answer (score 0):

Look at the verse below from the Quran

> Oh you who believe! Fear Allah and give up what remains of your demand for usury if you are indeed believers.
>
> If you do not, **take notice of war from Allah and his Messenger** but if you repent you shall have your capital sum. Deal not unjustly and you shall not be dealt with unjustly. ( Quran 2:278-279 )

Please see the bolded phrase "take notice of a war from Allah and His Messenger". I have not seen any sin in the entire Quran that is given this sort of punishment.

Do you know what this means?
It means you will be battling a lot of things in your life. The money will not let you live in peace.

Unfortunately even after such clarity, the sin of riba has crept deep into the Ummah.

I beg of you to please stay away from this sin.

Based on what you described, not only will your salary come from money your bank made thru riba but you are tasked with pushing other people into this sin ( its a sales job )

Comment: My personal experience has been very painful because of riba. After I gave up riba, it was as if a storm of troubles just stopped. Today I live in a rented place but I am much happier

Comment: Salam and welcome on Islam SE. Please consider taking our [tour], checking our [help] and read [answer] to learn how this site is supposed to work.